# Get the count of group by results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting count of some column by using `group by`. It returns results of the form,

### col1 count

date1   1

date2   2

I would like to further count on this result so that it returns `3`.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

```
SELECT t.p_date
,count(t.p_date) AS saturday
FROM t_p_booking t
WHERE t.p_id IN (
    220
    ,221
    )
AND dayofweek(t.p_date) = 7
AND date_format(t.p_date, '%Y%m') = : ccyymm
GROUP BY t.p_date
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `WITH ROLLUP` to the end of your `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: I think I was not clear in my question but I want only the total. And not an additional row.

Comment: Yep, you weren't clear. If you want just the final total then you should follow @BitWise answer

Answer (score 2):

Would that not just be:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM t_p_booking t
WHERE t.p_id IN (
    220
    ,221
    )
AND dayofweek(t.p_date) = 7
AND date_format(t.p_date, '%Y%m') = : ccyymm
GROUP BY t.p_date
```